# Delete an element from curl-json

Tags: php, json, curl

I can get data from a website with CURL and I can convert this data to json.

I want to remove an element from json.

Output:

```
{
        "test":{
            "numbers":
                [
                       "1",
                       "27",
                       "32",
                       "1",
                       "94",
                       "1",
                       "8"
                ]
        }
}
```

I want to remove "1" from my json. How can I do that? Thank you for your help.

my code:

```
<?php
function Curlconnect($start,$end,$website) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $website);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $website = curl_exec($ch);
    preg_match_all('@'.$start.'(.*?)'.$end.'@si',$website,$ver);
    return $ver[1];
    curl_close($ch);
}

function nt($start,$bit,$data,$a) {
    preg_match_all('@'.$start.'(.*?)'.$bit.'@si',$data,$ver);
    return $ver[1];
}

$url = 'http://www.url.com';
$getdata  = Curlconnect('<h4','h4>',$url);
$jsonData = ["data"];
$jsonData["numbers"] = [];
for ($a=0; $a<count($getdata); $a++) {
    $printdata = nt('>','</',$getdata[$a],$a);
    $jsonData["test"]["numbers"][] = $printdata[0];
}

echo json_encode($jsonData);
?>
```

Comment: try `foreach ($jsonData["test"]["numbers"] as $key => &$elem) if ($elem === "1") unset($jsonData["test"]["numbers"][$key]);`

Comment: thank you very much @user2464424 your code works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_search()` to look for a value in an array (your `$jsonData["test"]["numbers"]` array), and use `unset()` to remove the value from the array.

Because there are multiple "1" values, and `array_search()` only returns the first key found, you'll need to use a while loop to ensure you find all the values to remove.

```
function remove_value_from_array ($val, $array)
{
    while ( ($key = array_search($array, $val)) !== false)
    {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }

    return $array;
}

$jsonData["test"]["numbers"] = remove_value_from_array($jsonData["test"]["numbers"], "1");
```

---

**Edit**: I've remembered a simpler way - and a way that allow you to search for multiple values. You can simply use `array_diff()` to search for values, and remove them.

```
// Remove a single value of "1"
$jsonData["test"]["numbers"] = array_diff($jsonData["test"]["numbers"], array(1));

// Remove multiple values, of "1", "2", "5", and the word "test"
$jsonData["test"]["numbers"] = array_diff($jsonData["test"]["numbers"], array(1, 2, 5, "test"));
```

Comment: Hi @RobbieToyota your second code works perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @RobbieToyota, I tried your code and my result is
{
        "test":{
            "numbers":
                [
                     1:  "5",
                     2:  "27",
                     3: "32",
                     4: "41",
                     5:  "94",
                     6:  "27",
                     7:  "8"
                ]
        }
}

How can I remove 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 numbers from json?

Comment: @Johny Are you trying to remove the __value__ of 1-5 (only remove the `[1:"5"]` record), or the __key__ of 1-5 (the first 5 would be removed, leaving only `[6:"27",7:"8"]`)? The array_diff will work for the "search for values" case. If you want to remove based on the keys, you can use `array_diff_key()` - it works the same way, except it compares the array keys, rather than the array values.